# Paperclip - How do they create the timestamp appended to the file name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Paperclip to store images using S3. It's my understanding that Paperclip will append a string (timestamp) to the end of the image for caching purposes. Do you know what method they use to create the string? I need to rebuild it using .js, here's why:

I am getting content using jQuery's $.getJSON, parsing the response data, building an array and adding it to the DOM. Everything works great with that, but I need to add the string on to the end of the file name.

Here's an example:

```
<img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/some_bucket/some_image.jpg?1293603533" />
```

Although the URL is an example, the string appended to the file name is actual. Here is the other data on this image.

```
image_file_size: 159713 
image_height: 415   
image_width: 900    
image_updated_at: 2010-12-29 06:18:53
```

I thought it'd be as easy as stripping all ":" and "-" from the image_updated_at attribute but it doesn't look that easy. Is it completely random? Anyone have any idea on this? I'd appreciate a hand!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked into [Rails source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7aa847fab4da41bfa30fa356fc0d7d79b7081734/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb) and this `asset_id` is computed in this line:

```
File.mtime(path).to_i.to_s
```

So it is just converting `Time` object to integer. And [ruby docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000257) says that it is just number of seconds since epoch.

[Here](http://www.esqsoft.com/javascript_examples/date-to-epoch.htm) is example how to convert date in js to the same format as in ruby `to_i`. I've checked it and it gives the same value.

Comment: +1 Brilliant answer, thanks! I think it's helped me to see that I might need to change the way I'm going about this. I'd have to perform this calculation possibly 50 times each time I fetched a new 50 records. I think I'll have to either live with the fact that it will not get a cached version, or maybe build the content in a layout and get that via ajax. Thank you for the thorough answer!

Comment: Actually it isn't as intensive as I thought. I think I was overwhelmed by the example script. Was as easy as `new Date(image_updated_at).getTime() / 1000`

Comment: @jyoseph: yea, js Date stores miliseconds from epoch, so dividing it by 1000 solves the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Even better is to use `image_updated_at.to_i` - it also returns seconds from the epoch, with the added advantage of not touching the file system.