# Is there an easier way to insert a time stamp into a file name with Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Is there an easier way to insert a time stamp in a file name ?

```
def time_stamped_file(file)
  file.gsub(/\./,"_" + Time.now.strftime("%m-%d_%H-%M-%S") + '.') 
end

f = "test.txt"
puts time_stamped_file(f) 


=> test_01-24_12-56-33.txt
```

Comment: Probably not.  Note that you don't need to assign the string substitution back to the "file" variable since that action has no effect.

Comment: Thanks - good point about assigning back.  ..... changed that

Comment: File names are not required to contain extensions. It is also possible for them to contain multiple `.` characters. You should probably account for that if you want a general solution.

Comment: A minor improvement would be to include the separators in the pattern: `'test.txt'.gsub('.', Time.now.strftime("_%m-%d_%H-%M-%S."))`, but this still isn't very robust eg if there is more than one `.` in the filename.

Answer (score 10):

Not necessarily "easier," but here's a slightly more canonical and robust way to do it:

```
def timestamp_filename(file)
  dir  = File.dirname(file)
  base = File.basename(file, ".*")
  time = Time.now.to_i  # or format however you like
  ext  = File.extname(file)
  File.join(dir, "#{base}_#{time}#{ext}")
end

timestamp_filename("test.txt")     # => "./test_1359052544.txt"
timestamp_filename("test")         # => "./test_1359052544"
timestamp_filename("dir/test.csv") # => "dir/test_1359052544.csv"
```

Answer (score 3):

What about this? It worked for me.

```
time = Time.now
puts time.strftime("%m-%d-%Y.%H.%M.%S")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're just trying to create a uniquely named file and it doesn't have to contain the original filename, you could use the built-in Tempfile class:

```
require 'tempfile'

file = Tempfile.new('test')
file.path
#=> "/var/folders/bz/j5rz8c2n379949sxn9gwn9gr0000gn/T/test20130124-72354-cwohwv"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a shorter approach you (and dont care particularly about the accuracy of the the timestamp) you could adopt an approach similar to [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) as mention in the below SO post.

[Paperclip - How do they create the timestamp appended to the file name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4552728/paperclip-how-do-they-create-the-timestamp-appended-to-the-file-name)